# How to extract data from html table, and its inside table?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have a html table structure with some data in the main table and some in the nested table inside a td element.

I just want the required 5 data (with ** xx ** indication) so I can export it to Excel as one single row.

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="chart">
              <tr>
              <td>**Text 1**</td>         
                <td>
                  <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td>some useless data</td>
                      <td>**Text 2**</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
                <td>**Text 3**</td>
                <td>**Text 4**</td>
                <td>**Text 5**</td>
              </tr>
</table>
```

My Code is like this:

```
    for (Element row : excel.select("tr")) {
        // create row for each tag
        header = sheet.createRow(rowCount);
        // loop through all th tag
        Elements ths = row.select("th");
        int count = 0;
        for (Element element : ths) {
            // set header style
            cell = header.createCell(count);
            cell.setCellValue(element.text());
            cell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
            count++;
        }
        // now loop through all td tag
        Elements tds = row.select("td");
        count = 0;
        for (Element element : tds) {
            if(!element.text().isEmpty()){
                cell = header.createCell(count);
                cell.setCellValue(element.text());
                count++;
                }
        }
```

The problem here is that the output was not as expected.

It looks like this in Excel:

```
  Row1:  Text 1 | Text 2 | useless data | Text 2 | Text 3 | Text 4 | Text 5 |
  Row2:  useless data | Text 2 |
```

---

Additional Information:  tags are omitted for simplifying question.

What I want is

```
 Row1:  Text 1 | Text 2 | Text 3 | Text 4 | Text 5 |
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear to me. What is this second line in your output?Also, youo missed the TH rows from the html you provided. I guess the ```<td>``` element containing the inner table returns with something non-empty if you call its td.text() method, which is why the 3rd output column is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Two rows**

I guess `excel` is the document or the table. Anyway, when you select 
`excel.select("tr")` you also pick up the inner table `tr`. To prevent this, you need to make the css selector more specific. If I assume `excel` to be the Document, I can do this

```
Elements outerTrs = excel.select("table.chart>tbody>tr");
```

in the context of your code:

```
for (Element row : excel.select("table.chart>tbody>tr")) {
```

Explanation:
Jsoup creates a `tbody` element inside a table if it is not present. With the selector I made sure only the direct child `tr` the elements of the outer table are selected I can do this, because I know the class name of the outer table and it seems unique.

**2. Unexpected number of columns**

This is due to the fact that your select `row.select("td")` statement picks up the `td` containing the inner table. if you want only tds with no child elements you could use this:

```
Elements tds = row.select("td");
count = 0;
for (Element element : tds) {
if(!element.text().isEmpty() && element.children().isEmpty()){
    count++;
    System.out.println("line "+count+" text = '"+element.text()+"'");
}
```

**3. useless data**

To get rid of this, you need to just filter it out. From your example it is not clear when useless data is present. Is it always the first `td` in the inner table? If so you can do this (full solution)

```
Document excel = Jsoup.parse(tab);

for (Element row : excel.select("table.chart>tbody>tr")) {
    Elements tds = row.select("td");
    int count = 0;

    Element junkTd = row.select("td table td").first();

    for (Element element : tds) {
        if(!element.text().isEmpty() 
                && element.children().isEmpty()
                && !element.equals(junkTd)){

            count++;
            System.out.println("line "+count+" text = '"+element.text()+"'");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **1** Now all data are gone  
**2** It was caused by the ** useless data **  
Now it becomes `Row1: Text 1 | useless data | Text 2 | Text 3 | Text 4 | Text 5 |`  
`Row2: useless data | Text 2 |`

Comment: Sorry, don't get it. What is the problem now? Maybe you want to create a new question or add the relevant info to this one (but don't change the meaning of the original question). Keep it short but sufficient to understand what you do, what you get and what you want to get.

Comment: The first method will return me an empty set of data. Thus I kept using original codes for that part. The second method suggested can barely do the job as the useless data still being captured.

Comment: The useless data is always the first td in inner table

Comment: please see my edit. it now should address all issues. Please read on css selectors so that you can adapt on your own if needed.